how to get branch name in Gitlab ci/cd
i have a gitlab ci config like this
simple build :
  stage: build 
  script:
    # i want to echo branch name here
rules :
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG    

i want to echo branch name as a variable
i tried to use $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH or $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME but both of these variable only works when the pipeline is triggered by a commit

If you want to echo the branch name as a variable, you can use the predefined CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME variable provided by GitLab. This variable contains the name of the branch or tag that is being built.
Here’s how you can modify your GitLab CI config:
simple_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Branch name: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: never  # Ensure this job is not run for tags

for configuration:
1). CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME: This variable holds the name of the branch or tag being built.
2). $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME: This variable script section to prints the branch name.
3). If $CI_COMMIT_TAG is defined, the job will be run (meaning the job will run only for this tags), which allows the job to only run for branches.
This setup configuration will echo the branch name when the job runs for branch builds.

it's not working as you wrote or maybe I have to say ChatGPT wrote,
1). CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME: This variable holds the name of the branch or tag being built.
when ci/cd is trigger by tag  the CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME wont contain branch name it will be the tag name only

Assuming you are inside of your git project directory, you could just ask git to output the current branch:

simple_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'


output of this command in HEAD because gitlab detach the last commit so git branch , git checkout and ... wont work

We had the same kind issue with Gitlab Pipeline only showing Tag or branch name depending on the pipeline source.
In our case we ended up by doing the other around, we used a "merge" pipeline where getting the branch name was easy with  $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME and a git command to get the tags:
get-tag:
  stage: get-tag
  script:    
    - TAG=$(git describe --exact-match --tags)
    - echo "Latest TAG is $TAG"
    - echo "TAG =${TAG}" >> dotenv.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: dotenv.env

Here

  - echo "TAG=${TAG}" >> dotenv.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: dotenv.env


Is optional and allow you to use the variable in later jobs in the pipeline
